# Load json from the same directory as .dll

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

How do i load a file (json in this case) in the same directory as the .dll file that uses it?

Programfolder/Plugins

In my case, the executable is in Programfolder and the dll and json in /plugins.

I tried this:

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class KeyCodes
    {
        public string RandomizeAllKey;
        public string RandomizeFaceKey;
        public string RandomizeBodyKey;
        public string RandomizeFaceBodyKey;
        public string RandomizeClothesKey;
    }

    string configFilename = "Randomizer.json";
    var configPath = $"{UserData.Path}..\\Plugins\\{configFilename}";
    var keys = JsonUtility.FromJson<KeyCodes>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(configPath));
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Perhaps (exploring) something like `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` would be helpful? There are a number of subtle variations depending on exact meaning, shadow assemblies, etc. - and an equal number of questions discussing each.

Comment: Are you looking for this `Environment.CurrentDirectory `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the path where your dll is running, use this:

```
// GetExecutingAssembly finds the path where THIS code is running
var dllPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string configFilename = "Randomizer.json";
var configPath = Path.Combine(dllPath, configFilename);
```